# mapping result of native query to a POJO without having a table corresponding to it created in the DB on query execution

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using Hibernate implementation of JPA (Hibernate version: 4.2.1, JPA version:
1.8.1). I have some native queries, the result of which are mapped to my list of custom POJOS (marked with @Entity). However, when the query executes, I get an empty table created in my MySQL schema featuring the attributes in my POJO. How do I ensure that no table gets added to my existing schema, considering that it is not possible to map native query results to a POJO without marking it as an "Entity".

**POJO**

```
package abc;
@Entity
public class Myclass
{
@Id
private Integer productId;
private String productName;
public MyClass(){
}
/**getters and setters for productId and productName**/
}
```

**CODE SNIPPET FOR EXECUTING NATIVE QUERY**

```
List<Integer> productIdList = new ArrayList<>();
productIdList.add(1);
productIdList.add(20);
productIdList.add(34); 
List<MyClass> myList=(List<MyClass>)(entityManager.createNativeQuery("select p.productId, p.productName from products p where p.productId IN (:productIdList)",MyClass.class).setParameter("productIdList", productIdList).getResultList());
```

Comment: This sounds very strange to me.  Can you include the relevant code?  Typically a native query should return type `List<Object>` for each record in the result set.

Comment: There is JPA 1.0, 2.0, 2.1. There is no JPA 1.8.1!

Comment: check your presistence.xml file for configuration  named as "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" and remove it. this configuration is used to create, update and remove table based on entity defined in code. Can you post your code  so that we can understand what are you doing exactly.

Comment: @Tim: Yes native query by default returns List<Object[]> when we don't map it to any custom POJO. But as you can see in the code above i have mapped my result set to my POJO i.e., MyClass.java

Comment: @Billy: I checked my pom.xml file which shows spring-data-jpa version as <spring.jpa.version>1.8.1.RELEASE</spring.jpa.version>. However, it also mentions <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
          </dependency>

Comment: @Navnath: I don't have "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" anywhere neither in my persistence.xml file nor in applicationContext.xml file....Then too I am facing this problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, for that I tried all possible values for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`  parameters but no luck. Simply, I would expect an option like `do_nothing` but in the documentation there is none like that. So my solution was to add `@Table("tbl_to_remove_<YourObjectName>")` to each entity
and remove all newly created tables that starts with `tbl_to_remove` in db manually and yes each time I restart my application.

From the community documentation: [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional) the possible options are listed

> hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto Automatically validates or exports schema DDL
>   to the database when the SessionFactory is created. With create-drop,
>   the database schema will be dropped when the SessionFactory is closed
>   explicitly.
>
> e.g. validate | update | create | create-drop

Comment: yes..that seems the only way now..but I guess there should be some way to prevent JPA executing DDL on DB every time the application is deployed

Comment: I would really be happy if you find a real answer for that and share with us.